# Move all footnotes, references, tables, and charts to end

Tags: packages

I'm submitting a paper for review for publication and the style guide of the journal requires:

> footnotes, references, tables, and charts on separate pages

I take this to mean that footnotes should be a separate page, references on another.

I know about the `endnotes` package, but are there other packages or style files that I can use to achieve this style requirement without changing the markup of my document extensively?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using `endnotes` and `endfloat`

In the preamble:

```
\usepackage{endnotes}
\usepackage{endfloat}

\let\footnote=\endnote
```

At the end of the document

```
\newpage
\begingroup
\parindent 0pt
\parskip 2ex
\def\enotesize{\normalsize}
\theendnotes
\endgroup

\newpage
\bibliographystyle{asr}
\bibliography{qp}

\end{document}
```

Comment: It would be great if you can show an example so that other users with the same problem can see a working solution.

Answer (score 0):

1. footnotes: as you mentioned, use the endnotes package and put a `\newpage` before and after it.
2. references: I guess that means you bibliograpy? If yes, newpage before and after `\bibliograpy`
3. tabulars and charts: put both inside a table or figure environment and set the placement specifier to `p`, see here: http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Floats,_Figures_and_Captions under »Floats«.

If I were you, I'd ask the editor how to comply with that rule you cited, maybe that will save some work...